# How to add html special character (right-arrow) using content property of css?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add html special character using its code. Its working fine when I use it inside my div but how can I do this using css.

I have tried as following.

```
.right-arrow:after {
    content:'&#9658'
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/q8v7c/)

**EDIT**

What I wanted is not there in Matt Ball's answer because I wanted code for right arrow and in that question there is code for down arrow only. So its not duplicate.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-escapes

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Special characters work a little bit different with pseudo-elements. You can't use HTML entities in CSS, but you can use Unicode hex escapes. Here is a tool to convert the numeric value of the special character to the CSS value.

http://www.evotech.net/articles/testjsentities.html

for example `&#9658` needs to be `\25BA`

working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/L6suy/

```css
.right-arrow:after {
  content: '\25BA \25BC \25C0 \25B2'
}
```

```html
<div class="right-arrow"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Its really nice.

Comment: Just to make the why a bit clearer: You can't use HTML entities in CSS, but you can use Unicode hex escapes

Comment: Just upvoted because of the link you shared :)

Comment: @SvenBieder Thanks, i've added your suggestion to the answer

Comment: I needed a left arrow. It's \25C4. Other variations here - https://codepoints.net/geometric_shapes

Comment: Whoa nice one. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

```
<div class="right-arrow">Arrow</div>
.right-arrow:before {
    content:'\25BA';
}
```

[See Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/q8v7c/1/)

Comment: Yea even I got the converter now :)